# Show key not values in reacti18next by configuration

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

We are using reacti18next for translating our app language. Every value is showing against keys. But we have a configuration in our app which is *enable blank localizer*.  When the configuration is enabled then the translation will show only keys.

Suppose we have implemented the translation key as shown below which shows the value of the key. Now We need to show the key name which is ***member-management.members.form.fields.name***. How could we do this? Any thought.

```
<Trans i18nKey="member-management.members.form.fields.name"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a special language called `cimode`, if you set / change your language to it, the `t` function will return keys instead of values.

So just invoke this whenever your app is in a special mode:

```js
i18n.changeLanguage('cimode');
```

For more info checkout
https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage

Comment: Let me check to my application